# Getting error on executing CLR procedure in sql server

Tags: sql-server, .net-assembly, clrstoredprocedure

I am using the microsoft sql server 2008. On executing the CLR procedure i am getting the below error.

> An error occurred in the Microsoft .NET Framework while trying to load
>   assembly id 65547. The server may be running out of resources, or the
>   assembly may not be trusted with PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS or
>   UNSAFE. Run the query again, or check documentation to see how to
>   solve the assembly trust issues. For more information about this
>   error:  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'clrprocedure, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. An error relating to security occurred.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013150A) System.IO.FileLoadException:
>   at System.Reflection.Assembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String
>   codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, Assembly locationHint,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(AssemblyName assemblyRef,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark,
>   Boolean forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)

Please suggest.

Comment: *check documentation to see how to solve the assembly trust issues*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long R&D, i got the solution.

The **TRUSTWORTHY** property of the database was turned **OFF** previously.

I turned it **ON** and now it is working fine for me.